# How did the designer achieve this Blue tint effect?

Tags: reverse-engineering, saturation, color-blue

I am looking through websites for web design inspiration (yes, I know I'm in the photography forum) and I'm trying to figure out how this blue tint was achieved on this photo? I have tried making the temperature colder on the photograph, raising the blue saturation globally, and increasing the contrast a bit; but it's not looking right...

Anybody have an idea of how this was achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like he created a blue layer and gave it opacity, after converting the picture layer to black and white.

So, make a new layer over your image, and flood-fill with blue. Then, set opacity %. Make sure this blue layer is higher than your picture layer.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is nothing but gradient map with layer blend.
Just add blue color to one corner picker(darker area) and blue- white(lighter area) to the other end.
Try different blending modes such as overlay and soft light.